# Redirect after a RedirectRule has taken place to other website

Tags: .htaccess

I have a website, let's say `www.example.com` but this used to be `www.example.nl`. All traffic from `www.example.nl` is now redirected to `www.example.com`, but as we changed some naming conventions, `www.example.nl/seeds` now has to redirect to `www.example.com/nl/flower-seeds`.

The `.htaccess` file I got contains the following code:
`RewriteEngine On`
`RewriteBase`
`RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !example.com$ [NC]`
`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L, R=301]`

`Redirect 301 /seeds/(.*) example.com/nl/flower-seeds/$1`

When I navigate to `www.example.nl/seeds/` I end up at `www.example.com/seeds/` which ends up in a 404 because I'm missing the `/nl/flower-` part.

I think Redirect doesn't work properly when the URL is already altered by a RewriteRule. How would you tackle this problem? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Are those two domains served by the same http server?

Comment: And the `example.com/nl/flower-seeds/$1` in the second rule does not make any sense. `example.com` will get interpreted as a _folder name_ . A URL starts with a scheme.

Answer (score 0):

You should exclude  `/seeds/` directory form general rules like this :

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !example.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/seeds/(.*)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L, R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^seeds/(.*)$ http://www.example.com/nl/flower-seeds/$1 [L, R=301]
```

**Note:** clear browser cache then test

Also , don't use regex with redirect like what you did :

```
Redirect 301 /seeds/(.*) example.com/nl/flower-seeds/$1
```

Here this `(.*)` has no meaning , you could use either `RedirectMatch or RewriteRule`